# OrientDB Creating an edge using select statement to set property

Tags: orientdb, graph-databases, orientdb2.2

I want to create an edge using a sub query to set a property. The following is the query i am using:

```
create edge HAS from #57:0 to #80:3 set Type = (select from A where ID = 1)
```

This gives me the following error:

```
OvalidationException:
The field 'HAS.Type' has been declared as LINK but the 
value is not a record or a record-id
```

Please note the **Type is a property of type LINK**.
Any help is appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is the answer:

```
create edge HAS from #57:0 to #80:3 set Type = first((select from A where ID = 1))
```